# jQuery AJAX response always returns blank message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

Hi I'am trying to make HTML form, and need to validate it before executing the form action. But the AJAX  respond always returns a blank message?

```
$(function(){
    $("#ajax-payment-form input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {

        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize data, make AJAX call
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: templateDir+"/payment_form/payment_process.php",
            data: str,
            context: this
        }).done(function(msg) {

            if(msg == 'OK') {
                 console.log('Validation passed, will submit form');
                 $(this).closest('form').submit();
            } else {
                 console.log(msg);
            }

        }).fail(function() {
            // Catch ajax errors here
            console.log('AJAX error');
        });
    });                                                         
});
```

PHP:

```
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if ($post) {
  $orderid = stripslashes($_POST['orderid']);
  $amount = stripslashes($_POST['amount']);
  $betingelser = stripslashes($_POST['betingelser']);
  $error = ''; // Check ordreid
  if (!$orderid) {
    $error. = 'Venligst indtast dit ordreid.<br />';
  } // Check amount
  if (!$amount) {
    $error. = 'Venligst indtast et beløb.<br />';
  }
  if (!$error) {
    echo 'OK';
  } else {
    echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.
    '</div>';
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong?

Comment: can you show me your php code for payment_process.php

Comment: success is deprecated?

Comment: @AbdulBasit yes here:

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{

 $orderid = stripslashes($_POST['orderid']);
 $amount = stripslashes($_POST['amount']);
 $betingelser = stripslashes($_POST['betingelser']);


 $error = '';

 // Check ordreid

 if(!$orderid)
 {
 $error .= 'Venligst indtast dit ordreid.<br />';
 }

 // Check amount

 if(!$amount)
 {
 $error .= 'Venligst indtast et beløb.<br />';
 }

 if(!$error)
 {
  echo 'OK';
 }
 else
 {
  echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
 }

}

Comment: console.log(str) , console log your strigified obj of form i think your "this" context is wrong, tell me if you have smthing in str

Comment: @user2717954 No, it's not. Don't tell people that. You should use `done`.

Comment: I would guess nothing gets sent to the post request, $(this) will be in context of the submit button and not the actual form wouldnt it?

Comment: 8 hours and this issues is still not fixed, i'am freaking out :/

Comment: @thar Verify that the server is actually outputting something. Use Chrome/Firefox's debugging tools to actually inspect the AJAX request and response, so you can figure out whether the problem is in JavaScript or PHP. Do some debugging.

Comment: @meagar in the console.log all i get is a blank message and a reference to theme.js

Comment: @thar Yes, I know, I'm telling you to ignore console.log and actually inspect the AJAX request and response. If you did that you'd probably see the problem right away.

Comment: Here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network This is the thing you should be using to diagnose AJAX problems. You can see the request, including all the data and headers, and there response exactly as rendered by the server. Before you assume the problem is in the JavaScript handling your response, you should check the JavaScript making your *request*.

Answer (score 1):

You're in the `click` handler of a `submit` button. You're calling `$(this).serialize()`, where `this` is that submit button. Calling serialize on the submit button is going to return an empty string.

So, you're not passing any data to the server. The first thing you do server-side is check `empty($_POST)`, which it *will be*, so `if ($post)` is false, and none of your server-side code is eve executed.

You need to serialize the **form**, not the submit button.

A simple solution would be to serialize the form itself....

```
str = $('"#ajax-payment-form').serialize()
```

but really, the larger problem is that you're binding to the `click` of the submit button, instead of to the `submit` event on the form itself.

Instead of this rather convoluted way of handling form submits...

```
$("#ajax-payment-form input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
```

Just do this:

```
$("#ajax-payment-form").submit(function (e) {
```

Comment: The problem is that when doing that, it create an infinity loop. log (1223)Validation passed, will submit form. (1223) counting up fast.

When setting str = $('"#ajax-payment-form').serialize() i got the right respont, bot the action is not been executing

Answer (score -2):

try this in jquery:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: templateDir+"/payment_form/payment_process.php",
data: str,
context: this,
success: function(msg){
if(msg == 'OK') {
    console.log('Validation passed, will submit form');
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
    } 
else {
    console.log(msg);
}
}
error: function(msg){
// if call fails or any error occurs
}
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using done/fail callbacks on the promise returned by `$.ajax`. It's generally much nicer to work with than passing in the equivalent success/error callbacks.